# Convert DB2 SQL Decimal to time

Tags: sql, db2

Convert DB2 SQL Decimal to time
I need to convert Decimal to time. I have a decimal time field that contains data like this :

123490 --12:34:90 
4506 --00:45:06 
171205 --17:12:05

etc

I would like to convert into time format then i calculate min between two times columns

Is there anyway to do this with SQL commands or DB2 logic in a select statement?

Comment: 3600*(dectime/10000) + 60*MOD(dectime/100,100) + MOD(dectime,100) turns decimal time to seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert it to a valid time format you have to do some string manipulations like

```
cast( substr( right( '00' || '123456', 6) ,1,2) || ':' || substr( right( '00' || '123456', 6) ,3,2) || ':' || substr( right( '00' || '123456', 6) ,5,2) as time)
```

where 123456 is your decimal. This would work for your 4506 example as well. 
You could of cause also use a case statement if you want to avaoid adding the "00" each time.

For calculating the difference in minues there might be other calc options.
You can check out the [minutes_between function provided by Db2 11.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061479.html)

Comment: You are welcome - if yoiu get tinmes with only two digits like for 00:0:41 you just have to add four 0 instead of the two.

Comment: Sir i have 4 columns in decimal
datein        || timein      ||  Dateout     || Timeout
20180501  || 093012   || 20180501  || 103012
20180501  || 233013   || 20180502  || 042012
how to calculate minutes

Comment: Which OS and which version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TO_DATE`, which is short version for `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`, but you first need to convert decimal to string.

```
select time(to_date(digits(cast(143513 as dec(6,0))),'HH24MISS')) from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

- `cast` is there just to simulate 6 digit decimal
- `digits` converts decimal to char, padding it with zeros
- `to_date` converts string to timestamp, based on the format string. [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-timestamp-format)
- `time` returns the time portion of a timestamp

This is based on iSeries version of DB2 but should work for LUW as well.