# Convert DB2 Decimal with three or four chars to a valid time

Tags: c#, sql, time, db2

In the database we have times stored as decimal. Some places it is stored as three digits and and other it is stored as four digits.

e.g.

```
0415 
 415
```

Time must be `04:15`, and I am using a 24hr clock.

I have tried using the `cast` statement from the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080212/convert-db2-sql-decimal-to-time) and it works perfectly where time is represented as 4 digit decimal. However I get a null value when time is represented as 3 digits.

Can anyone suggest a statement which will work with both three digits and four digit decimal and convert it to time.

Thanks to GMB

The following works but not for values like 400, 500, 600 etc. A little progress but I would have not got here without GMB's help

This works:

```
SELECT cast( cast(floor(0415/100) as varchar(2)) || ':' || cast(MOD(415,100) as varchar(2)) as time ) FROM "SYSIBM".SYSDUMMY1
```

This does not work:

```
 SELECT cast( cast(floor(0400/100) as varchar(2)) || ':' || cast(MOD(400,100) as varchar(2)) as time ) FROM "SYSIBM".SYSDUMMY1
```

Note the code is for DB2 iSeries version, if you are running LUW DB2 use the answer from GMB.

Any help on why it does not work for values like 400, 500 etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could use number arithmetics to get the hour and minutes part, then cast to strings, concatenate, and cast to time:

```
cast(
    cast(floor(dec/100) as varchar(2)) || ':' || cast(dec%100 as varchar(2))
    as time
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d58fc69e40a778aa23a312d650eb032d)**:

```
create table t (dec decimal(10, 2));
insert into t values (415), (2359)

select dec, cast(
    cast(floor(dec/100) as varchar(2))
    || ':' 
    || cast(dec%100 as varchar(2))
as time) res 
from t
```

```
    DEC |      RES
------: | -------:
 415.00 | 04:15:00
2359.00 | 23:59:00
```

Comment: I am really new with who DB2 syntax. I like your answer. How to cast a single decimal value to Time. I tried this and it fails.

SELECT 
cast(
    cast(floor(0415/100) as varchar(2)) || ':' || cast(415%100 as varchar(2))
    as time
) FROM "SYSIBM".SYSDUMMY1

Comment: @Abe: why do you mean by *it fails*? Are you getting an error? Wrong results? I tested your code and it seems to work fine [in this DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=57b8047797ef98ec04eca64a39c7a4fc).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I am using DBeaver and I get an error if i were to run the above modified statement I get an error  - Keyword 'as' not expected

Comment: Any thoughts? I am using DB2 and the IDE i use to query the DB is DBEaver. Any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: @Abe: I have no specific knowledge in DBeaver so I cannot really tell... If you run the query I provided in my answer (that starts with `with...`), do you get the same error?

Comment: Sorry I have only been using DBeaver for past few weeks. Which statement are you referring to? From nfgl's answer?

Comment: No I mean the statements in my answer itself (`create table`, `insert`, then `select`).

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to create any tables at the moment all I can do is select.

Comment: I am using a different version of DB2 iSeries not the LUW version. I had to use the MOD function instead of % symbol.

Comment: @Abe: ahh ok, that explains the problem. Thanks for sharing the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_timestamp()

with input as decimal(4, 0)

```
select
  time(to_timestamp(digits(time_as_dec_4),'HH24MI')) time
from (values dec(0415,4),dec(415,4)) data (time_as_dec_4)
```

or as varchar

```
select
  time(to_timestamp(lpad(time_as_char, 4, '0'),'HH24MI')) time
from (values '0415', '415') data (time_as_char)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to construct this as a string:

```
select lpad(floor(time / 100), 2, '0') concat ':' concat lpad(time % 60, 2, '0')
```

You can then convert this to a `time`, if you like.

Comment: The below statement happily converts 0415 to 04:15
select CAST( SUBSTR( RIGHT( '00' || '0415', 6) ,3,2) || ':' || SUBSTR( RIGHT( '00' || '0415', 6) ,5,2) AS TIME) FROM "SYSIBM".SYSDUMMY1